# spread operator form submission in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Can spread operator solve below problem? Imagine I have more fields, then I have to declare req.body.something for every single fields, that's so tedious.

```
app.use((res,req,next) => {
  const obj = {
     name: req.body.name,
     age: req.body.age,
     gender: req.body.gender
  }
  //
  User.saveUser(resp => res.json(resp)) //User model
})
```

Comment: I think it should be `req, res, next`, not `res, req, next`?

Comment: if you want to use everything: `const obj = req.body`? can't see `obj` used btw.

Comment: @Jorg There is a comment below `const obj = ...` statement. I guess OP means the use of `obj` object is ignored.

Comment: There is no "spread operator". There is a `...` punctuator, which is used in [*spread syntax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=spread+syntax) and rest parameters. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const obj = req.body;
const { name, age, gender } = obj;
```

But, still you will have to validate it, and count all of them in your scheme.

**Update:**

Adding some validation example.
Assuming such schema in your route:

```
const tv4 = require('tv4');

const schema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    name: 'string',
    age: number,
    gender: {
      type: 'string',
      pattern: /f|m/i
    }
  },
  required: ['name']
};
```

And then, in your handler you validate:

```
if (tv4.validate(req.body, schema) {
 // continue your logic here
} else {
 // return 400 status here
}
```

Comment: validation is a pain in express, any library you recommend? Mongoose has built in validator as well, can I just use that?

Comment: I use jsonScheme to describe what I expect and tv4 npm module to validate objects in scheme. No pain, all smooth.

Comment: @JennyMok you can use lodash's `.has()` to validate `req.body`. Please check my answer.

Comment: It's totally not the same. Using scheme you say which properties are requried, you say each type, you can tell how to validate each (pattern)... It's very flexible tool.

Comment: @Lazyexpert ah, understand. If OP need complex JSON structure validation, JSON Schema is the better choice.

Comment: i have to have 2 schema which has duplication code then, ouch. One in the route file and one in my models.

Comment: @JennyMok I saw some modules that compile one schema type from another. But I didn't test them much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick)'s `pick()`:

> **_.pick(object, [paths])**
>
> Creates an object composed of the picked object properties.

Example code is:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
...
const obj = _.pick(req.body, ['name', 'age', 'gender']);
```

If `gender` does not exist in `req.body`, it would be ignored -- the result `obj` object won't have a `gender` field.

---

If all the `req.body` fields are needed, you can just assign `req.body` to `obj`:

```
const obj = req.body;
```

---

To validate `req.body` content, you can use lodash's `.has()`:

> **_.has(object, path)**
>
> Checks if path is a direct property of object.

Example code would be:

```
_.has(req.body, ['name', 'age', 'gender']); // return true if all fields exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring assignment

```
const { name, age, gender } = req.body
```

or if you wanna use spread operation, you can use :

```
const obj = { ...req.body }
```

Hope it helps!